# output elements of an array containing particular letter in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, syntax, include

I'm new to javascript and I'm struggling with getting the syntax right on my function to pull elements from an array containing the letter 'i'.

```
let teachers = ["Arrington", "Kincart", "Alberts", "Pickett"]

let rooms = [
  ["Andy", "Rodolfo", "Lynn", "Talia"],
  ["Al", "Ross", "Jorge", "Dante"],
  ["Nick", "Kim", "Jasmine", "Dorothy"],
  ["Adam", "Grayson", "Aliyah", "Alexa"]
]

let iInName = (teacher) => {
  let nameWithI = []
  teachers.forEach((withI) => {
    if(teacher.includes('i') {
    nameWithI.push(withI)
  }
})
return nameWithI
}

iInName()
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated. This is my first time posting on here; if I am missing any info or overlooking any etiquette, I am happy to address!

Comment: Please show us the complete code. What you posted seems to miss the declaration of `teachers` and the first line of the function.

Comment: What is the syntax error that you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to use the forEach method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

`withI` is passed to this function ([callback](https://www.learn-js.org/en/Callbacks)) which you have defined. `teachers` is the array of names, `withI` is called for each name.

`if(teacher.includes('i')` should be `if(withI.includes('i'))` since `withI` is the name of the teacher.

You might also want to look into [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
function iInName(teachers) {
  let nameWithI = []
  teachers.forEach((withI) => { // A function or commonly referred to as a callback
    if(withI.includes('i') { // Changed from teachers (of type array)
      nameWithI.push(withI)  // To withI (type string)
    }
  })
  /*
   return teachers.filter((name) => {
      return name.includes('i') // Keeps value if true
    })
  */
  // return teachers.filter(name => name.includes('i'))
  return nameWithI
}
iInName(['joe', 'marie']) // Any array
```

You only need one of the three solutions, one is commented out with `/*` and `*/`, another with `//`. The one most similar is uncommented (used).

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight.

Comment: No problem ^-^. Do you need any further assistance? If not, you can choose this answer as the one that answered your question.